# Once-each-turn Abilities with Controller Changes

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Quirion Ranger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quirion%20Ranger) has an ability with the restriction :"Activate only once each turn".

If the ability is activated, then later on the same turn control of the Ranger changes, can the new controller activate the ability?

Is the answer any different for [Mairsil, the Pretender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mairsil%2C%20the%20Pretender)'s ability; "...You may activate each of those abilities only once each turn."?

**EDIT**: on rereading the last ability of Mairsil, only the owner of the exiled cards can activate their abilities, so that question is moot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rule 602.5b](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Activated_ability):

> If an activated ability has a restriction on its use (for example, “Activate only once each turn”), the restriction continues to apply to that object even if its controller changes.